How to create a JSON with an array of objects including null values using AWS Glue and Spark?
I am working on a data transformation pipeline using AWS Glue with Apache Spark. My goal is to create a JSON output that contains an array of objects where all fields are included, even if they contain null values.
Currently, the output is in the following format:
{
    "identifier": "1015604061WS",
    "values": { ... }
}
{
    "identifier": "1019502238WS",
    "values": { ... }
}

But I need the result to explicitly include all objects inside an array, like this:
[
    {
        "identifier": "1015604061WS",
        "values": { ... }
    },
    {
        "identifier": "1019502238WS",
        "values": { ... }
    }
]

Here is my current approach:
spark = glueContext.spark_session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("GlueJob") \
    .config("spark.sql.jsonGenerator.ignoreNullFields", "false") \
    .getOrCreate()
job = Job(glueContext)

def map_unit(unit_column):
    return when(col(unit_column) == 'M', 'METER') \
           .when(col(unit_column) == 'KG', 'KILOGRAM') \
           .when(col(unit_column) == 'M3', 'CUBIC_METER') \
           .when(col(unit_column) == 'MM', 'MILLIMETER') \
           .otherwise(col(unit_column))

def create_structure(column_name, unit_column):
    return when(
        (col(column_name) != 0) & (col(unit_column).isNotNull()) & (col(unit_column) != ""),
        array(struct(
            lit(None).alias("locale"),
            lit(None).alias("scope"),
            struct(
                col(column_name).cast("float").alias("amount"), 
                map_unit(unit_column).alias("unit")
            ).alias("data")
        ))
    ).otherwise(None)

def create_currency_structure(column_name, currency_column):
    return when(
        (col(column_name) != 0) & (col(currency_column).isNotNull()) & (col(currency_column) != ""),
        array(struct(
            lit(None).alias("locale"),
            lit(None).alias("scope"),
            array(struct(col(column_name).cast("float").alias("amount"), col(currency_column).alias("currency"))).alias("data")
        ))
    ).otherwise(None)

database_name = "project_example"
table_name = "input"
df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database=database_name, 
    table_name=table_name,
    transformation_ctx="catalog_node"
).toDF()

df = df.filter(col('material').isNotNull()).withColumnRenamed('material', 'identifier')

df = df.withColumn('erp_name', array(struct(
    when(lit("de_DE") == "", None).otherwise(lit("de_DE")).alias("locale"),
    lit(None).alias("scope"),
    col('materialkurztext').alias("data")
)))

df = df.withColumn('ean13', array(struct(
    lit(None).alias("locale"),
    lit(None).alias("scope"),
    regexp_replace(col('ean13'), "^'", "").cast('string').alias("data")
)))

df = df.withColumn('internal_note', array(struct(
    lit("de_DE").alias("locale"),
    lit(None).alias("scope"),
    col('`int.Vermerk`').alias("data")  # Usar backticks para nombres con caracteres especiales
)))

df = df.withColumn('expiry_date', array(struct(
    lit(None).alias("locale"),
    lit(None).alias("scope"),
    col('auslaufdatum').cast("string").alias("data")
)))

df = df.withColumn('country_iso_code', array(struct(
    lit(None).alias("locale"),
    lit(None).alias("scope"),
    col('ursprungsland').alias("data")
)))

df = df.withColumn('material_type', array(struct(
    lit(None).alias("locale"),
    lit(None).alias("scope"),
    col('materialart').alias("data")
)))

df = df.withColumn('packaging_quantity', array(struct(
    lit(None).alias("locale"),
    lit(None).alias("scope"),
    col('verpackungsmenge').alias("data")
)))

df = df.withColumn('pruftext', array(struct(
    lit("de_DE").alias("locale"),
    lit(None).alias("scope"),
    col('prüftext').alias("data")
)))

df = df.withColumn('ean128', array(struct(
    lit("de_DE").alias("locale"),
    lit(None).alias("scope"),
    regexp_replace(col('ean128'), "^'", "").cast('string').alias("data")
)))

df = df.withColumn('lhm_menge', array(struct(
    lit(None).alias("locale"),
    lit(None).alias("scope"),
    regexp_replace(col('`pal.-Mng.`'), "^'", "").cast('string').alias("data")
)))

df = df.withColumn('rotho_colors', array(struct(
    lit(None).alias("locale"),
    lit(None).alias("scope"),
    array(regexp_replace(col('Farbcode'), "^'", "").cast('string')).alias("data")  # Eliminar ' al inicio
)))

df = df.withColumn('inside_length', create_structure('Innenlänge', 'Innenmaßeinheit')) \
       .withColumn('inside_width', create_structure('Innenbreite', 'Innenmaßeinheit')) \
       .withColumn('inside_height', create_structure('Innenhöhe', 'Innenmaßeinheit')) \
       .withColumn('diagonal', create_structure('Diagonale', 'Innenmaßeinheit'))

df = df.withColumn('gross_weigth', create_structure('bruttogewicht st', 'gewichtseinheit st')) \
       .withColumn('nett_weigth', create_structure('nettogewicht st', 'gewichtseinheit st'))

df = df.withColumn('uvp', create_currency_structure('unverbindliche preisempfehlung', 'uvp w'))

df = df.withColumn('volume', create_structure('volumen st', 'volumeneinheit st'))

df = df.withColumn('length', create_structure('länge st', 'abmessungseinheit st')) \
       .withColumn('width', create_structure('breite st', 'abmessungseinheit st')) \
       .withColumn('height', create_structure('höhe st', 'abmessungseinheit st'))

df = df.withColumn('length_vpe', create_structure('länge vpe', 'abmessungseinheit vpe')) \
       .withColumn('width_vpe', create_structure('breite vpe', 'abmessungseinheit vpe')) \
       .withColumn('heigth_vpe', create_structure('höhe vpe', 'abmessungseinheit vpe'))

df = df.withColumn('gross_weigth_vpe', create_structure('bruttogewicht vpe', 'gewichtseinheit vpe')) \
       .withColumn('nett_weigth_vpe', create_structure('vpe nettogewicht', 'gewichtseinheit vpe'))

df = df.withColumn("values", struct(
    col('erp_name').alias("erp_name"),
    when(col('inside_length').isNotNull(), col('inside_length')).alias("inside_length"),
    when(col('inside_width').isNotNull(), col('inside_width')).alias("inside_width"),
    when(col('inside_height').isNotNull(), col('inside_height')).alias("inside_height"),
    when(col('diagonal').isNotNull(), col('diagonal')).alias("diagonal"),
    when(col('gross_weigth').isNotNull(), col('gross_weigth')).alias("gross_weigth"),
    when(col('nett_weigth').isNotNull(), col('nett_weigth')).alias("nett_weigth"),
    col('ean13').alias("ean13"),
    when(col('uvp').isNotNull(), col('uvp')).alias("uvp"),
    col('internal_note').alias("internal_note"),
    col('expiry_date').alias("expiry_date"),
    when(col('volume').isNotNull(), col('volume')).alias("volume"),
    col('country_iso_code').alias("country_iso_code"),
    col('material_type').alias("material_type"),
    when(col('length').isNotNull(), col('length')).alias("length"),
    when(col('width').isNotNull(), col('width')).alias("width"),
    when(col('height').isNotNull(), col('height')).alias("height"),
    col('packaging_quantity').alias("packaging_quantity"),
    col('pruftext').alias("pruftext"),
    col('ean128').alias("ean128"),
    when(col('length_vpe').isNotNull(), col('length_vpe')).alias("length_vpe"),
    when(col('width_vpe').isNotNull(), col('width_vpe')).alias("width_vpe"),
    when(col('heigth_vpe').isNotNull(), col('heigth_vpe')).alias("heigth_vpe"),
    when(col('gross_weigth_vpe').isNotNull(), col('gross_weigth_vpe')).alias("gross_weigth_vpe"),
    when(col('nett_weigth_vpe').isNotNull(), col('nett_weigth_vpe')).alias("nett_weigth_vpe"),
    # col('lhm_menge').alias("lhm_menge"),
    col('rotho_colors').alias("rotho_colors")
))

df_transformed = df.select('identifier', 'values')

output_path = "s3://project_example/export"

df_transformed.write.json(output_path, mode='overwrite', ignoreNullFields=False)

job.commit() 

How can I ensure that the JSON output contains all objects in an array format while preserving null values?
Environment:

AWS Glue version: 4.0
Python 3

Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

I encountered the solution when trying to create a JSON file from a DataFrame in AWS Glue, where I needed to filter out specific fields that were null. This is the code that solved the problem by dynamically removing fields with null values from the values field in each row.
Here's the solution:
Define the fields to be checked: I listed all the fields that should be excluded from the final JSON if they have null values.
Function to filter null fields: The function filter_null_fields converts each row into a dictionary and removes the fields that are null based on the predefined list of fields (fields_to_check).
Data transformation and JSON export: The transformed data is then converted to a JSON string and uploaded to S3 using boto3.
import json
import boto3
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Define the fields that should be removed if they are null
fields_to_check = [
    'inside_length', 'inside_width', 'inside_height', 'diagonal',
    'gross_weigth', 'nett_weigth', 'uvp', 'expiry_date',
    'volume', 'length', 'width', 'height',
    'length_vpe', 'width_vpe', 'heigth_vpe',
    'gross_weigth_vpe', 'nett_weigth_vpe'
]

def filter_null_fields(row):
    """ 
    Function to remove fields from 'values' that are null 
    for the fields defined in 'fields_to_check'
    """
    row_dict = row.asDict(recursive=True)  # Convert the row to a dictionary
    values = row_dict.get('values', {})
    
    # Remove fields that are null
    filtered_values = {k: v for k, v in values.items() if k not in fields_to_check or v is not None}
    row_dict['values'] = filtered_values
    
    return row_dict

# Select the necessary fields from the DataFrame
df_transformed = df.select('identifier', 'values')

# Convert the DataFrame into a list of dictionaries, filtering out null fields
data_list = [filter_null_fields(row) for row in df_transformed.collect()]

# Convert the list of dictionaries into a JSON string with an array format
json_array = json.dumps(data_list, indent=2)

# Define the output bucket and path in S3
output_bucket = "project_example"
output_path = "export/output.json"

# Use boto3 to write the JSON file to S3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# Upload the JSON file to S3
s3.put_object(
    Bucket=output_bucket,
    Key=output_path,
    Body=json_array,
    ContentType='application/json'
)

# Commit the job
job.commit()


With this approach, any fields from the list (fields_to_check) that are null will be completely excluded from the values section in the final JSON. The JSON file is then successfully uploaded to S3 with the desired format.
This solved my problem, and I hope it helps you too!
